# Python - Array of member variables from an array of class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm analysing a bunch of data that is timestamped. I've created a class that holds one datapoint, and the data associated with that point (here it's shown with only a couple of other values, but this could be a larger collection of metadata (numbers and text):

```
class SpectrumDataPoint(object):

    def __init__(self, timestamp, num_average, frame_time):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self. num_average = num_average
        self.frame_time = frame_time
```

Then, I append these points into a list inside a loop (not shown):

```
point = SpectrumDataPoint(datetime.datetime.now(), var1, var2)
spec.append(point)
```

What I'd like to do now is plot the data against the timestamps to look for trends. For example, I might like to plot `timestamp` against `num_average`.

Is it possible to plot the data in this way, without having to iterate over the list to create new copies of the data in memory? If so, how?

I was hoping that something like `spec[1:10].num_average` would work.

Comment: You don't have an array of classes, you have a list of instances.

Comment: Matplotlib might do you what you need to do here?

Comment: Agree that matplotlib is the way to plot this. It's the process of getting at the data that I'm trying to understand rather than the plotting - I suppose that my question wasn't too clear about this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right. Bad terminology on my part when formulating the post title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matplotlib` handles timestamps, so you only need to extract the value pairs.

```
t = []
vals = []

for spec in specs:
    t.append(spec.timestamp)
    vals.append(spec.num_average)
```

and then, just plot it

```
plt.plot(t, vals)
plt.show()
```

There is no syntax like `spec[1:10].num_average`. The closest thing is a list comprehension `[s.num_average for s in spec[1:10]]`. However, even if it existed, it would still iterate under the hood. matplotlib will need arrays (consecutive memory locations), and your values belong to different objects.

However, even for millions of points, the iteration time will be negligible. The real bottleneck will be the plotting itself, which will practically crash every time with millions of points.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that there was a way to do this without having to iterate over the list (under the assumption that it'll take ages when I've got lots of points).